Google API: Use pagetoken with batch
I don't know how to use the pagetoken with the Google batch.
I don't know if I should put the batch in a function and call it from callback
This is my code.
How could I do it? (the code is imcomplete)
def audit(user):
service = build('admin', 'reports_v1', credentials=credentials())

def callback(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception:
        # Handle error
        print(exception)
    else:
        parseResult(response.get('items', []), user)
    return response

batch = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)

page_token = None

while True:
    param = {}
    if page_token:
        param['pageToken'] = page_token

    batch.add(service.activities().list(userKey=user, applicationName='drive', 
                                        filters="primary_event==true,
                                        startTime="2024-01-05T00:00:00+02:00",
                                        endTime="2024-01-20T23:59:00+02:00",
                                        eventName="download",
                                        pageToken=page_token,
                                        maxResults=100))
    batch.add(service.activities().list(userKey=user, applicationName='drive',
                                            filters="primary_event==true,
                                            startTime="2024-01-05T00:00:00+02:00",
                                            endTime="2024-01-20T23:59:00+02:00",
                                            eventName="print",
                                            pageToken=page_token,
                                            maxResults=100))

    #page_token = ?????.get('nextPageToken')

    if page_token is None:
        result = batch.execute()
        #parseResult(completeResult)
        return


You can't use the same page token for two different lists. It's like trying to share a single bookmark across two books. Personally I'd just not use batch to start with if possible, but if you must do so, you need to have a separate page token for each of your list operations... and you also need to write appropriate code so that if one of the lists has "finished" you don't keep adding requests for it.

Thanks, I hadn't realized that each list has its pagetoken. In any case, I would like to know the technical procedure to process pagetokens in batches. See if anyone is encouraged.

Batch is really just "here's one HTTP request, but it contains multiple logical requests, and the HTTP response will contain multiple logical responses". Think of "how to do pagination" and "how to do batching" entirely separately - I would say that combining the two is going to be relatively ugly in terms of the code, but if you really want to do it, you just need to think "what's the next request for each logical list" and batch those together.
